# What would be the best way to cancel a task, if you want to re run the same task?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, task

I'm currently working with hit animations for a character, I need the system to wait until the animation is finished for the system to move forward, but I also need to make multiple hits to the same character, so I'm looking for the best way to interrupt the await I have that is checking to see if the hit animation is currently playing.

```
internal async Task Hit(uint hit)
{
    //should I put a cancel token here? Or somewhere else?
    _cancelToken.Cancel();
    animator.SetBool("idle", false);
    animator.SetBool("hit", true);
    //Need to be able to interrupt and play the hit animation again.
    await IsHitAnimFinished("hit");
    animator.SetBool("hit", false);
}
protected async Task IsHitAnimFinished(string name)
{
    var isFinished = false;

    while (!isFinished)
    {
        //Not working, need a better solution.
        if (_cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (CheckIfHitIsPlaying())
        {
            isFinished = true;
        }
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: Again: Stop using tasks but coroutines you can easily `StartCoroutine` and `StopCoroutine` .. but for some reason you "chose not to" .. ^^

Comment: @derHugo you actually don't know what you're talking about as the unity API works perfectly fine with Tasks, I suggest you do your own research and stop trying to push your own answers on people, if you don't have the answer or it's too advanced for you just don't bother answering as you're wasting my time: https://gametorrahod.com/unity-and-async-await/#:~:text=async%20already%20works%20in%20Unity,by%20checking%20completion%20every%20frame.

Comment: fair enough, didn't know this tbh. So far async stuff in Unity was always quite tricky. But then what exactly is the question? Pass in the CancelationToken into the task and let it check if it was canceled.

Comment: if i understand correctly, would your problem not be fixed by moving the `animator.SetBool("hit", false);` at the end of `Hit()` to be inside the `if(CheckIfHitIsPlaying())` body, that way you would only be setting this variable when the action was completed sucessfully (not canceled)?